# Does http protocol version "HTTP/1.1" include https?

Tags: java, apache, http

I actually don't see this question already asked, perhaps because it is so basic.

I'm working with Java Apache httpcomponent, and inspecting the return of:

> `HttpResponse response.getStatusLine()`
>   returns:
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK

I made the Apache HttpPost = new HttpPost("https://login.blah.com/etc");

Does this mean that I successfully am using Https with this connection (ie, my connection has successfully used HTTPS and not regular HTTP) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

HTTP and HTTPS are from the content that is being sent on application level indiferrent.

HTTPS is basically HTTP through a TLS tunnel.

So when the connection is established it is HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response!