# index.php to root in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, http-status-code-301

What does this mean? I am trying to remove index.php from the URL and point to root. For example,
https://www.example.com/index.php redirect to https://www.example.com/ 
The below solution works absolutely fine. However, I am unclear about the HTTP/ used in RewriteCond line. What does it do? Can someone please explain?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.aviatrix.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664388/does-http-protocol-version-http-1-1-include-https

Comment: Why don't you simply take a short look into the documentation of the tool you use and _read_ what is contained in `%{THE_REQUEST}`?